# Find the matrix B of T with respect to the basis of V with B being on a two variable form

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

Linear Algebra with applications 5th edition chapter 4.3 question 66.

Let $V$ be in the linear space of all functions in two variables of the form

$q(x_1,x_2) = ax_1^2 + bx_1x_2 + x_2^2$

Consider the linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow V$:
$$T(f)=x_2 \frac{df}{dx_1} - x_1 \frac{df}{dx_2}$$

a) Find the matrix B to T with respect to the basis $x_1^2, x_1 x_2, x_2^2$ of $V$.

b) Find bases of the kernel and image of $T$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! We ask you to please use MathJax to write out equations for clarity. Formatting tips [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0):

with b being subscript b
a) A = [[T(x1^2)]b , [T(x1x2)]b , [T(x2^2)]b] = [0 -1 0 , 2 0 -2 , 0 1 0]

b) Note that rref(A) = [1 0 -1 , 0 1 0 , 0 0 0]. Now im(B) = span ([0 , 2 , 0] , [-1 , 0 , 1]

and ker(A) = span [1 , 0 , 1] Thus 2x1x2, - x1^2 + x2^2 is a basis of im(T) and x1^2+ x2^2 is a basis of ker(T)

But how do we justify a) and b). There are steps missing.